# How to combine two different table data into one table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to develop a report which needs to combine *employee* table and *leave* table together into one

> Employee Table

```
employeecode  calldate     doctorvisit 
E001          2017/08/03    Doc001
E002          2017/08/05    Doc002
E003          2017/08/10    Doc003
```

> Leave Table

```
employeecode    leavedate      leavetype
E001           2017/08/09      casualleave
E002           2017/08/17      sickleave
E003           2017/08/15      casualleve
```

> My output table

```
employeecode     Dates          fulldetails
E001          2017/08/03           1
E001          2017/08/09       casualleave
E002          2017/08/05           1
E002          2017/08/17        sickleave
E003          2017/08/10           1 
E003          2017/08/15       casualleve
```

**Query**

```
select emp.employeecode,
       case when emp.startdate = emp.startdate then emp.startdate = emp.startdate 
            when lea.calldate = lea.calldate then lea.calldate = lea.calldate  
            else null 
       end as dates,
       case when emp.startdate = emp.startdate then count(doctorvisit) 
            when lea.calldate =lea.calldate then lea.leavetype 
       end as fulldetails 

from employee emp
inner join leave lea on lea.employeecode = emp.employeecode

group by emp.employeecode,emp.calldate,lea.leavedate
```

When I execute this query its only showing *employee* table details not *leave* details but I need both details.

So please help me on this code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*? Merge or append? Please post desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility:

```
drop table if exists employee;
create table employee(employeecode text, calldate date, doctorvisit text);
insert into employee values
('E001','2017/08/03','Doc001'),
('E002','2017/08/05','Doc002'),
('E003','2017/08/10','Doc003');

drop table if exists leave;
create table leave(employeecode text, leavedate date, leavetype text);
insert into leave values
('E001','2017/08/09','casualleave'),
('E002','2017/08/17','sickleave'),
('E003','2017/08/15','casualleve');

select * from
  (
  select employeecode,calldate as dates,'1' as fulldetails from employee
  union
  select employeecode,leavedate as dates,leavetype as fulldetails from leave
  ) t
order by employeecode,dates;
```

Comment: Just to say to be careful with those `DROP` statements.

Comment: This is just for testing again and again from a script so you don't have to manually type them all the time :)  They are not meant for production use.

Comment: Yes, I got it. But OP couldn't. Here is another way to make script idempotent: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/29a93/1/0). Good answer, tho.

Comment: thank you @tonypdmtr  this query is completly working